Expected String or bytes-like object, got 'float'
I'm trying to make an ETL (Extract, transform and load) algorithm with python. I got an amazon review database, but when i use the DataFrame.apply() method to apply the function with regex i got the error:
expected string or bytes-like object, got 'float'
The code i've used is the following:
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
#from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

nltk.download('stopwords')
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

#Create the pattern for regex ETL process
pattern = re.compile(r"[\u0041-\u1EFF\s]+\s?")

def iterator_func (x):
    match = pattern.search(x[1])
    return "".join(i for i in match.groups() if i not in stop_words)


try:
    #Open the database, create a connection and upload the data to a database after the ETL process.
    with open(pathlib.Path("database\\test.csv"), encoding="utf-8") as f:
        csv_table = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)

    #Remove incorret values from the first index, stop words and ponctuation characters using regex and nltk
    csv_table[1] = csv_table.apply(iterator_func)
    csv_table[2] = csv_table[2].apply(iterator_func)

Here you can download and check the database: Amazon reviews on kaggle
I've tried to manually iterate over each row, and it works well, but i've noticed that will have serious performance issues.
   for x in csv_table.index():
        if csv_table.loc[x, 0] != "1" or csv_table.loc[x, 0] != "2":
            csv_table.drop(x, inplace=True, erros="ignore")
        #TODO: Create a regex function to avoid numbers, pontuations and stop words.
        temp_phrase = "".join(i for i in pattern.findall(csv_table.loc[x, 1]) if i not in stop_words)

        temp_phrase_two = "".join(i for i in pattern.findall(csv_table.loc[x, 2]) if i not in stop_words)

        csv_table.loc[x, 1] = temp_phrase

        csv_table.loc[x, 2] = temp_phrase_two


Can you show the full stack trace?  It is not clear which object is giving you. expected string or bytes-like object, got 'float'

So, you won't post the traceback telling us where the bug is? The big is likely where you apply to the entire table instead of just column 1.

I just tried to convert the type of a column to the correct type and that work fine.
csv_table[1] = csv_table[1].astype("str")


What type was it before? You also selected a single column, that may well be the only fix needed.
